# AngularJS select doesn't honour selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ASP.NET MVC controller with a VideModel I serialize into JSON and send to the client, along with a view and marry those two together using AngularJS. The view model has a lookup (array) that is bound to a Select element. It all works fine and I can select a value, post the form back to the MVC controller and get the selected value there.

When I send back a view model with a value already selected, the value is not selected in the Select element. I can see that the value is correctly set on the client side (using Batarang) but the Select still doesn't show that as selected. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0p7mlfsa65v0bo/AngularMVC.zip)'s a link to the sample showing this. Any ideas?

Here's the code snippets to give you some ideas (angular controller doesn't have any code, just a mean to add new item with default values to the destination array).

MVC Controller:

```
public Sources {
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}

public ActionResult MyGetAction() 
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel {
       Sources = SelectListExtension.ToSelectListItem<Sources>() //Would return IEnumerable<SelectListItem> (with proper Value and Text for all enum entries)
       Destination = new List<DestinationViewModel>(); //Has int? SourceId
    };

    vm.ClientData = SerializeToJson(vm);

    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPostAction(MyViewModel model)
{
   var selectedSource = model.Destination[0].SourceId; //works fine
   model.Sources = SelectListExtension.ToSelectListItem<Sources>(); //populate the lookup again
   //model still has 1 destination with the SourceId correctly set
   return View(model);
}
```

My View bound to the JSON object:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div ng-repeat="destination in Destinations">

      <select ng-init="destination.Source = { Value: destination.SourceId }"
              ng-model="destination.Source"
              ng-options="s.Text for s in Source track by s.Value"
              ng-change="destination.SourceId = destination.Source.Value"
              name="Destinations[{{$index}}].SourceId"
              id="Destinations_{{$index}}__SourceId">
         <option value=""></option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <input type="submit">
}
```

Comment: In this expression `ng-options="s.Text for s in Source track by s.Value"`, should `Source` be `Sources`? Also if Sources is array. How does one object in it look?

Comment: @Chandermani I have attached a sample with code, etc. to the question. That should make it clearer what I want to achieve.